# Getting the JSON data from cloudant

Tags: swift, cloudant

I have a database created in Cloudant and I am trying to parse that data in my Swift project. I have imported the Cloudant libraries, but I am not able to parse the data.

Here is the code that I Have been using till now

```
var url = "https://username:password@cloudant.com/dashboard.html#/database/db_2/login_details"
var request = NSMutableURLRequest()
request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
    let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary
    if jsonResult != nil {
        if let item = json[0] {
            if let student_name = item["Student_name"] {
                if let pasword = student_name["password"] {
                    println("Login Successfull")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: try unwrapping your url NSURL(string: url)!

Comment: What's going wrong? An Error? Incorrect Behaviour? The Flying Spahetti Monster ate your only bagel when you tried to run the code? You'll need to provide more details about what "I am not able to parse the data." means in your situation.

Comment: This code is doing nothing.. That's what i mean by not parsing the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) to convert any special characters your link may have. Also NSURL may return nil so you need to use if let to handle it as follow :

```
if let link = "https://username:password@cloudant.com/dashboard.html#/database/db_2/login_details".stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: link) {
        println("valid Url")
        // your code
    } else {
        println("invalid Url")
    }
}
```